# Testing Live Ads Before Publishing Admob

Tags: unity

I am testing ads with the test device method and test ads are showing perfectly but when I try to load live ads they won't load.

I have implemented the OnAdFailedToLoad which tells me that ads are not loading, this only happens when I try to load live ad but in the test ad everything works fine.

Does this happens all the time? we can't see live ads without publishing the game first? or there are no ads available at the moment if so when do the get available or they even get available for new users. How can I make sure that I will get live ads after publishing the on Google Play Store.

I don't know I am just confuse about this thing, I am using Unity 3D and building for Android.

I have searched on internet but everybody says that ads might not available at the moment I am just curious why are ads not available its been two days and I haven't seen any ad when are the ads going to be available. Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a new app with admob, it usually takes a couple days to run ads on consistent basis. Once you publish your app and your app starts making more ad request, live ads will be running without a problem. If test ads are working properly then there's no problem with your app networking with admob. so don't worry. Just publish the app with live ads ID. :)

Remember! if you get live ads showing on your own device, google might see that as invalid activity and that might get your admob account suspended. and trust me THEY WILL SEE THAT.